# iPad App with 'protected' settings

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I need to write an iPad App that has some settings modifiable by users and other reserved settings modifiable by an Administrator: I intend that some settings are password protected, like Restrictions are protected by PassCode.
So, does anyone knows if is it possible to protect some application custom settings using passcode (or something like passcode) and how ?

Any suggestion or hint is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the settings you have in the "settings" default iphone app, then you cannot do that. you can only choose from predefined settings type,

Answer (score 0):

If not using the "settings" default, you can create a seperate file and place your setting variables there (for example you want a user to change the background color, or something else that is "code simple"). And then open that file in the viewDidLoad function. 
If that is what you are talking about I am happy to explain further.